# How to Reload a Php Page Based on a Stored Time in Mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, time, reload

I am a beginner at this and I would like to know how it is possible to reload a php page based on a stored time in database(MYSQL). I know you can set a certain time to reload the page by using META REFRESH but in this case reloading time is not fixed(certain) and is based on the time(duration) stored in mysql database. The stored time(duration) in database is different for every item.

I guess i need a javascript code to do that. Any help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript function `setTimeout("function_called", interval)` and `window.location="url"` to do this.

Comment: can you be more spesific how to do it? plz. I am a beginner.